# Pegando as coordenadas do mouse fora do JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Eu tenho um JFrame implementado de forma simples com MouseMotionListener em java para pegar as coordenadas de uma variavel, e estou retornando com o getY() e o getX(). Até ai tudo bem, mas quando eu observei as coordenadas mostrada no JFrame, são exatamente as coordenadas de dentro do JFrame, quando o mouse ultrapassar as bordas da janela as coordenadas não são mais reinscritas. Qual procedimento ou classe ou meio, que em Java, me permita "escutar de fora do frame" o movimento do cursor do mouse ?

Comment: Forneça um **[mcve]** para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Esse é o metodo que utilizei pra pegar o movimento dentro do JFrame:
    Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        posicaoY.setText(Integer.toString(e.getY()));
        posicaoX.setText(Integer.toString(e.getX()));
    }

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [esta resposta do Soen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420208/5524514), é possivel obter as coordenadas do mouse, mesmo fora do JFrame, com os métodos abaixo, originados da classe [`MouseInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html):

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
```

Comment: Esse método tem a mesma função do getY(), e getX, no pacote java.awt eu queria ver se existe como pegar direto do sistema operacional (se é que a JVM consegue enxergar depois). Porém do exemplo passado referente a outro tópico, o usuário simulou uma janela abaixo da tela lançada do JFrame, é uma tecnica interessante vou estudar mais sobre ela. Vlw.

Comment: @Rivaldodossantos Eu mesmo testei aqui e funcionou normalmente, ele capta exatamente a posicao do mouse na tela, independente se o mouse está sobre o jframe ou nao. Acho que provavelmente vc nao conhece bem a API, o awt pega tudo do sistema operacional.

Comment: Certo dentro de mouseMover implementei assim:

Comment: public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        posicaoY.setText(Integer.toString(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y));
        posicaoX.setText(Integer.toString(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x));

Comment: posicaoY e posicaoX é uma JLabel, o componente que vc utilizou para visualizar é do pacote javax.swing ou do java.awt ??? Como foi que voce implementou ?

Comment: @Rivaldodossantos fiz exatamente como está na minha resposta.

Comment: Ok, mais no seu metodo addMotionListener o que voce adicionou no parametro ou no teu addMouseEvent??

Comment: @Rivaldodossantos repito, eu fiz exatamente como está na minha resposta, nao usei nada disso q vc ta falando ai. Se a resposta não deu a solução exatamente da forma que lhe ajude, sugiro que [Melhore a pergunta](/help/how-to-ask). Neste link tem orientações sobre como editar e melhorá-la.

Comment: @Articuno há alguma forma de falar com você fora do site? ;)